# VBA Script Stops Part Way Through File List

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following VBA code meant to loop through a given folder and compile all files of a certain type into one single worksheet.

```
  Sub cons_data()

Dim Master As Workbook
Dim sourceBook As Workbook
Dim sourceData As Worksheet
Dim CurrentFileName As String
Dim myPath As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim lRow As Long
Dim i As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'The folder containing the files to be recap'd
myPath = "path"

'Finds the name of the first file of type .xls in the current directory
CurrentFileName = Dir(myPath & "\*.txt*")

'Create a workbook for the recap report
Set Master = ThisWorkbook

For i = 1 To Master.Worksheets.Count
    With Master.Worksheets(i)
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If lRow > 1 Then .Rows("2:" & lRow).ClearContents
    End With
Next i

Do
    Workbooks.Open (myPath & "\" & CurrentFileName)
    Set sourceBook = Workbooks(CurrentFileName)
    For i = 1 To sourceBook.Worksheets.Count
        Set sourceData = sourceBook.Worksheets(i)

        With sourceData
            LastRow = Master.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            .Rows("2:" & lRow).Copy Master.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(LastRow + 1)
        End With
    Next i

    sourceBook.Close

'Calling DIR w/o argument finds the next .txt file within the current directory.
CurrentFileName = Dir()
Loop While CurrentFileName <> ""

MsgBox "Done"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

This script works fine on certain file types, but for some reason when running it on a list of text files with a standard format (some of which are duplicates) it stops and presents the most recent entry it was working on in a separate Excel sheet. Is there any obvious reason looking at the code that this might be happening?

Comment: I just ran this code on one of my folders and had no problem. Perhaps you could add some debug.prints. What do you mean by 'some are duplicates'?

Comment: Same here ran several times with no problem. Just one question why do you clear all worksheets on workbook `Master` if only one (`Sheet1`) is being used?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn I just mean that there are some files that have the same name and content. Good point on the debug.prints. If it helps, I have something like 20,000 files I'm looking to go through - could that create some issues?

Comment: `some files that have the same name and content` - How do you get two (or more) files with the same name in a single directory??

Comment: `LastRow = Master.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` should be `LastRow = Master.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Master.Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`, but I doubt if that is the cause of your problem.

Comment: @YowE3K Whoops, misspoke, they have similar titles and identical content.

Comment: Does it always stop at the same file, or is it a different file each time?  If it is always the same file, is there anything "funny" about its filename?  (I thought a leading space may confuse it because Excel might `Trim` the filename when creating its indexes but, although it took me a while to generate such a filename, I tested it and it worked OK.  But there might be other funny characters that might cause issues.)

Answer (score -1):

You need to kill old processes and discharge resources memory by adding after :

```
Set sourceBook = nothing
```

After

```
sourceBook.close
```

Hope this can help

Comment: See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2004/04/28/when-are-you-required-to-set-objects-to-nothing/). The reference is released each time through the loop.

Comment: I have manipulated batch of Excel files by SSIS. These files had different format and in addition there was in shared mode, other in exclusive mode. I have some crashes and by monitoring my Tasks Manager, I noticed the residual files processes that was still there and which were causing the crash of my SSIS processing. Using this SET syntaxe SET appExcel = nothing remedied my processing problem.
It is in this precise context of processing a large mass of Excel files where this syntax (even no longer be used) could be used.
I ask that your valuation of my 2 points to be reconsidered.